# Jasper reports JRXhtmlExporter only working in IE

Tags: java, jasper-reports, reporting

Trying to generate jasper report in XHTML format using JRXhtmlExporter, but its only working fine in Internet Explorer, and not in any other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc.; not giving any error but only showing loading window for infinite times.

```
JRXhtmlExporter exporter = new JRXhtmlExporter();
reportDestLocation = REPORT_NAME+".html";
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream );
Map imagesMap = new HashMap();
request.getSession().setAttribute("IMAGES_MAP", imagesMap);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_MAP, imagesMap);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_OUTPUT_IMAGES_TO_DIR, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_DIR_NAME,request.getRealPath("images/"));
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI,"images/");
exporter.exportReport();
inFile = new File(reportDestLocation);
```

If I use JRHtmlExporter then its working in all browsers; but I have to use only JRXhtmlExporter here. 
Can any one give the reason; thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean `but its only working fine in Internet Explorer`? Is it Java applet?

Comment: @AlexK no its not Java applet, its only exporter class similar to JRHtmlExporter thanks.

Comment: Did you find any way?? I am facing the same problem and I am unable to display image in Firefox but with the same file if I open in IE I can see the image.